# Force superclasses to include a no-argument constructor

Tags: java, spring-mvc, constructor, controller

Regarding Spring Controllers; when a Constructor is included, a no-arg constructor must be included as well otherwise a 'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException' occurs. This message is very vague and caused me some headache.

We currently have an abstract controller class which most of our controllers extend from. It appeared that when my controller extended this class (Which has a 1 arg constructor), suddenly I received the 'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException'.

I'd like to help future developers (or even myself in the future) by forcing anyone extending the abstract controller to include a no-arg constructor. Is this possible?

**Edit, adding code for clarity**

Here's the class most of the controllers extend from, it includes a few helper methods:

```
public class AbstractController
{
     private String sessionName;
     // other attributes / final variables

     public AbstractController(String sessionName)
     {
         this.sessionName = sessionName;
     }

     public boolean isCommandInSession(HttpSession session)
     {
         return session.getAttribute(sessionName) != null;
     }

     // Other helper methods which include use of 'sessionName'
}
```

Example of one of many controllers, which works fine. Without the default constructor, or with only overriding the 1 arg constructor this controller will fail with 'NoSuchBeanDefinitionException'

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes(SomeController.COMMAND)
@RequestMapping(SomeController.URL)
public class SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    private String command = "someUniqueSessionName";

    public SomeController()
    {
        super(COMMAND);
    }
}
```

Comment: No. But a developer using Spring should understand both the rules of inheritance, and the rules of Sprijg injection. If someone defines a controller (or any other Sring bean) with a constructor having an argument that can't be injected, then some training is probably needed. I strongly suggest avoiding no-arg constructors, and using constructor injection.

Comment: @JBNizet We use a 1 argument constructor for the Session name, having all controllers override it with their own session names. I'd have to talk to the application architect If I wanted to change this

Comment: @JBNizet In your opinion is there anything wrong with the current setup? (Controllers override a 1 argument constructor, developers should know to include a 0 arg constructor when extending)

Comment: Sounds like session name should be a qualifier. If that's an actual user session name, then it shouldn't really be a property I think, as that stuff is in request context anyway.

Comment: Everything would be so much easier if you posted the code instead of describing it.

Comment: Added code for clarity. I should mention the AbstractController has other methods which take advantage of the 'sessionName' variable.

Comment: I stand by my previous comment. If the developer creates a controller with a constructor that takes a session name as argument, then he/she doesn't understand 1. how Spring injection works, 2. what the role of the sessionName and the design of the base abstract class is. So I'd insist on documentation and training. You could make it easier by not requiring the session name in the constructor, and by replacing that with an abstract getSessionName() method that subclasses must implement. But if Spring and the design are misunderstood, you'll have other problems anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor as below:

```
public class AbstractController
{    
     public boolean isCommandInSession(HttpSession session)
     {
         return session.getAttribute(getSessionName()) != null;
     }

     abstract String getSessionName();
}
```